# Map Loading in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I am very new to this map functionality in android. I do not have Google API installed in my SDK. Please help me in installing GoogleAPI.
I looked for lot of documents. But I didnt get any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have to install google API in your android sdk then for loading google map

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Vashisth..Please help me in what way i can do that.

Comment: Thanks Pratik..Help me in installing google API..

Comment: in Eclipse: Window->SDK Manager and download Google API for platform you wish to develop...

Comment: THanks vtuhtan..From where i can download??

Answer (score 2):

Well first you have to load SDK Manager. Then under the required api version select the "Google APIs" and install it. Then all you have to do is create a new project using the installed Google API. (Not using the standard Android SDK).

Comment: Thanks Dipsomania..In my case the option "Google APIs" is not showing in my SDK..\

Comment: In that case try updating the ADT Plugin for eclipse. To do that simply go to eclipse => Help => Check For Updates. If there's any, install all updates. Then relaunch eclipse and try SDK Manager again.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you installed the SDK, you can use the SDK manager to install the corresponding google apis
Refer this link : https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing

Comment: Thanks Kiran Kumar..I referred that link..In that it is showing Google API version to select..But in my case in my SDK it is not showing..

Comment: You might have to update your SDK manager and also your eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

just follow these steps :

open eclipse --> click on "windows" option --> after that select Android SDK Manager --> there you have to upgrade/install your google API for required version

[image: Android avd manager]

Comment: Thanks Nipun Gogia...But in my case in SDK the option(what u have highlighted) is not showing for me..